# Jquery DataGrid Finding Row

Tags: jquery, datagrid, find, background-color

I would like to find a particular row having red background-color in an asp datagrid using jquery's find() or filter() functions and selectors. The most efficient method is preferred.

I thought it would be something similar to $('#<%=Grid.ClientID %>').find('tr.background-color:red')...

Thank you in advance for your input,
Justin